# Magento 2: moment is not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, momentjs, magento2

I'm trying to use the Shipping Time JS plugin on my Magento 2 website, it requires both moment.js and jQuery in order to work however it's not working. I'm getting a **ReferenceError: moment is not defined** in shiptime.js on line 49 which is the following:

```
try {
        if (moment === undefined || $ === undefined ) throw Error("please include jquery & moment.js");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

==============

## My require.js

This is what my requirejs-config.js looks like, it's sitting in app/design/frontend/##/##/requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
packages: [{
    name: 'momentjs',
    location: 'js/',
    main: 'moment'
}],
map: {
    '*': {
        'menu': 'Magento_Theme/js/disable-menu',
        'shippingtime': 'js/shiptime'
    }
},
shim: {
   'momentjs': {
       deps: ['jquery']
   },
  'shippingtime': {
      deps: ['jquery',',momentjs']
  }
}
```

};

jQuery is loaded elsewhere and is definitely being loaded (I have various other jQuery libraries which are all working).

==============

## Debugging

I initially thought the moment.js/shiptime.js files weren't being loaded in however they are when I check both the source and the network panel. To further test this, I did the following to see if moment.js would output anything:

```
require(['momentjs'], function (moment) {

        console.log(moment().format('LLLL'));
    });
```

This does output the date in the console so moment.js is definitely loading, this is my code for the shiptime.js file which isn't working and gives me the error I mentioned above:

```
require(['jquery', 'shippingtime', 'momentjs'], function (moment) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(function($) {
                jQuery('.shipping-time').shipTime();
            });
        });
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you may have an extra `,` on `line 18` of your `require.js`? ```deps:['jquery',',momentjs']```

Comment: @dusthaines Good catch! I've removed the extra comma but it's still giving me the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with `requirejs` but since no one smarter has chimed in yet I'm happy to help you keep troubleshooting. Using `jQuery` with `requirejs` can be tricky, especially with a large and complex platform like Magento.

**Without being able to see all of your code I would consider and investigate the following:**

1. Are you initializing `jQuery` properly in a no-conflict way if necessary
2. Are you using `require()` vs. `define()` where and as intended
3. Are you versed in the challenges unique to `Magento` when using `requirejs`
4. Have you reviewed and followed the recommendations regarding the complexities of using `moment` with `requirejs`

**Here is some corresponding reading on each:**

1. [On No-Conflict](https://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap)
2. [require() vs define() plus other good insights](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/)
3. [On Magento 2 with RequireJS](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/)
4. On complexities of Moment and RequireJS

   1. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/
   2. https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1554#issuecomment-226269905

**One last thing to try:**

In your final code example you pass `moment` to the function but not `jQuery`. Have you tried something along these lines:

```
require(['jquery', 'momentjs', 'shippingtime'], function($, moment) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shipping-time').shipTime();
  });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the links, I spent a few hours rewriting all of it and I think I must've missed something out because it's working as intended now.

Thanks again for the response! :)